# RWeverything / He do not working on windows 11

Tags: windows, debugging, tooltip, bios, uefi

I used to use RWEverything to debug pcie and acpi related issue, to read/write registers etc.

After updating windows build (Windows11 22H2 10.0.22621.755) RWEverything stopped working, and every time I try to started error msg. it now doesn't work at all!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/drNuR.png)

Any help is appreciated, Thanks.

Note: tried reinstalling the app, tried many version of the app. Even tried the portable version of the app no luck.

How to make RWEverything / HW work with latest Windows 11.

**One more query (not sure if a separate question thread should be raised)**

I tried to disable core isolation by
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\DeviceGuard\Scenarios]
"HypervisorEnforcedCodeIntegrity"=dword:0000000

but unluckily, it does not work with registry change, whenever reboot system, and go to core isolation setting (memory integrity) and found it is still enabled.

one day, tried to manually disable it from setting and reboot system. it finally work.

after that, registry control also start working, with 0 to disable and with 1 to enable.

but my question is why previously my setup doe not work?
I really need a way to disable it by registry or other way instead of user manual change from GUI. any suggestions.

OS is:
Win 11 enterprise.
Build 22621.ni_release.220506

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To run RW Everything 1.7 on Windows 11 you need to:

1. Disable "Memory Integrity" feature.
2. Set to zero this key HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\CI\Config\VulnerableDriverBlocklistEnable

Comment: Thanks for your answer, also I modified a lot other registry as well as yours.
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\DeviceGuard\Scenarios\HypervisorEnforcedCodeIntegrity]

btw, Is there a way to disable "Memory Integrity" feature also by a windows command or kind of registry, or others. just want to know if there is a easy way to make it work.

Comment: Could you please help check my second query about the core isolation disablement. came across twice in two system.